# Server connection channel channel auth rule needs to follow

Tags: ibm-mq

How to ensure that the users of a particular SVRCONN channel provide a user ID and password while other SVRCONN channels may continue to work unauthenticated.
How can we do this?
which command is correct?

- Set CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) for the AUTHINFO and CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) for the channel CHLAUTH rule.
- Set CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) for the AUTHINFO and CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) for the channel CHLAUTH rule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is simply posting Q&A from the certification review test.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is simply posting Q&A from the certification review test.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

> Set CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) for the AUTHINFO and CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED) for the channel CHLAUTH rule.

When you set CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) if no password is sent it will not be validated, this will allow for channels to continue to work unauthenticated.  On channels where you want to require a user ID and password it you can use a CHLAUTH rule to set it to CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED).  Note that if this is a CHLAUTH rule that is going to match only a subset of connections (for example a ADDRESSMAP or USERMAP rule) you must put in a rule to deny all other connections like a ADDRESSMAP rule with ADDRESS(*) and USERSRC(NOACCESS).

If your have MQ Classes for Java or JMS clients connecting you need to ensure they do not pass a password value where you want things to work unauthenticated, if a value is passed, MQ will verify it is correct.

Comment: @Onit 
  
 
If my answer your question helped please follow the feedback in the Help Center article "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)". Specifically rather than say thank you, vote the answer up and accept the answer if it solved your problem. To accept you click the "Check Mark" that is below the down arrow under the number next to the answer, to vote it up click the up arrow next to the answer.